# Does anyone know of a Restlet Filter to JSONPify the response?

Tags: java, jsonp, restlet

I need to support JSONP by my Restlet JAX-RS server and the most natural and unobtrusive way to implement it is by having a dedicated Restlet `Filter`.

So, it occurred to me that I could not be the first one to be needing it. On the other hand google search yields nil.

Does anyone know anything about it?

P.S.

I know how to write it, in fact I am doing it right now. However, there are too much details to handle and looks like I am going to hardcode some expectations relevant to my server only. Naturally, I prefer something ready and tested.

Answer (score 1):

There are now JsonpRepresentation and JsonpFilter classes available in the org.restlet.ext.json module, contributed by Mark.

Comment: Hi Jerome, maybe you can share some idea with this Restlet issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794041/using-xstream-extension-with-swagger-instead-of-jackson